# Tick fell into dog's ear

Tags: dogs, safety, grooming

3 month old German Shepherd dog. This morning I found a tick in his ear, a bit deeper than usual. I got out a tweezer and carefully got it removed. However it seems the tick has fallen into his ear as he struggled when it was removed and it fell.

Should I take him to a vet as soon as possible or will it be fine and will the tick walk out of his ear? This was a reindeer tick, not a engorging one.

Answer (score 3):

If the tick is still inside the ear today you need to take your dog to your vet to get it removed,it is very uncomfortable for your dog to have a tick inside the ear and it might stress your dog.

Do not try to remove the tick yourself as the risk of injury to the inner part of the ear is too great,one wrong move from your dog and you will have to go to the vet anyway.